# Could a stone age civilization independently figure out about quantum mechanics

Tags: alternate-history, alternate-worlds, mathematics, quantum, stoneage

I was thinking of a stone age civilization that figures out how to use Quantum Mechanics.  This civilization figures out some of the equations that describe Quantum Mechanics, and comes up with first principles that also describe Quantum Mechanics.

This civilization is as advanced technologically as it has ever been.  It also has Mathematics that is more advanced than humans during the stone age.

Would this be possible, and if so what circumstances would lead a stone age civilization to figure out how to use Quantum Mechanics?

Comment: In what sense is this civilization "stone age" if it has mathematics?

Comment: This is really far-fetched. Unless you provide some sort of "magical" explanation, like knowledge imparted by the gods, or psychic energy beings I don't see how it could happen.

Comment: @Priska In the sense that they do not smelt metal for tools, and use entirely natural materials like stone and bone. Y'know, like the Aztecs or the Inca.

Comment: This is an incoherent question. It is not clear what you are trying to find out.

Comment: Without a complete recounting of the history of the development of civilization from the stone-age to at least the level of tech available in the west in the 1900's (which would be off-topic, too broad), I'm genuinely not sure what you're looking for here. Voting to close as off-topic unclear what you are asking until you can [edit] to clarify the specific issue you are having in making your world.

Answer (score 7):

Mathematics development has been strongly bond to practical necessities until very recent times.

You need to count your sheep or carrots? Here you are your integers.

You need to measure your fields after each flood? Here is your trigonometry.

You need to count your money deposit? Here you are your relative numbers.

And so on and so forth, until modular arithmetic to have secure internet transactions.

Stone age civilization has no need for quantum mechanics, because there is nothing noticeably quantum in their life. The sun rises, the clouds give rain, the arrow hits the animal or the animal kills the hunter.

Arrows don't quantum tunnel through rocks, there is no Schrödinger's deer, there are no boxes to contain it.

Pythagoras discovered the properties of $\sqrt2$ and kept them secret, and he was not a stone age dweller.

Comment: Imho "implausible" does not mean "impossible".

Comment: Archimedes discovered lots of things, but that the square root of two is an irrational number he learned at school -- it had been known for several centuries. (Cough, Pythagorean school, cough.)

Comment: @AlexP you got me.. there was something not sounding right in that sentence...

Answer (score 2):

**No**

L. Dutch's answer has a good point about practical origins of mathematics, but I think it should be expanded.

Even if stone age civilization would somehow develop a mathematical apparatus suitable for describing quantum mechanics, they would completely lack any experimental base to develop this theory.

Stone age civilization, by definition, can not invent cathode ray, can not measure photoelectric effect or come even close to comprehending [Planck's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law).

For this civilization, any mathematical formulae used in quantum calculations would appear more distant from reality than psychedelic poetry.

Answer (score 0):

A civilization? No. A lone mathematical genius within that civilization? Yes--but with the proviso that he would not call it "quantum mechanics", and it would have no obvious physical application.

As L.Dutch pointed out, mathematics has been strongly tied to practicality until fairly recent times. To set this up, you need two branches of mathematics to have already been developed for practical purposes: probability, and analytic geometry (with trigonometry as a prerequisite).

Probability was only developed in depth fairly late in our history, but there are all sorts of reasons why it could have been profitably developed earlier. Maybe your stone-age civilization has already figured out insurance and actuarial tables. Or maybe they're just really big on gambling, and you've got well-paid groups of mathematicians competing with each other to figure out on one hand how to beat the house, and on the other hand how to design games in which the house cannot ever be beaten.

Trigonometry is useful in surveying and architecture. And even very basic analytic geometry makes a lot of trigonometric problems, as well as more general surveying and architecture problems, considerably easier. The key insight is going to be figuring out the properties of vector arithmetic so as to develop the mathematical structure of complex numbers and generalized units, without necessarily going through the same route that we did in our history (i.e., as an offshoot of trying to find the roots of cubic equations just for kicks). If you have a stone-age Carl Friedrich Gauss, he might be able to do that and the next bit all on his own, but it might be more reasonable to have algebraic trigonometry fortuitously pre-developed as part of practical engineering first.

With those two fields already well understood, you are set up to have a lone genius messing around one day think "I wonder what happens if I replace all of the numbers in probability theory with two-dimensional vectors...."; or, he could think "I wonder if it makes any sense for probabilities to be negative..." and from there work out that he has to introduce vector quantities with distributions normalized over the Euclidean 2-norm rather than the usual 1-norm to make that work.

This will remain as an idle curiosity with no practical application (because while the mathematical system does make sense, this genius is unable to find any real-world examples of probability distributions that work this way) which will likely be forgotten about for thousands of years until quantum effects are discovered for real, and then some archeological dig uncovers tablets detailing this stone-age mathematician's discoveries and triggers a wave of conspiracy theories about the ancients were so much more advanced than us.

Comment: Would this mathematician be able to independently come up with the Mathematics describing Quantum Spin, Quantum Entanglement, and Quantum Fields as well?

Comment: @AndersGustafson Entanglement, yes. Spin, probably not. Quantum fields, definitely not. There would be no reason to imagine the latter two ideas.

Comment: @AndersGustafson Absolutely not. Quantum mechanics was developed to explain how bodies emitted electromagnetic radiation without producing almost infinite amounts of it. Phenomena that cannot be experienced by a palaeolithic culture. They would need a knowledge of the rest of the physics discovered up until the late 19th century.